# I have a while loop at the top of my script and want it to keep running after I do something else later on

Tags: python

I have a while loop that runs at the top of my code. After the input, the while loop stops checking the variable, I want it to always check the variable.

```
example = 1
while example == 1:

    print("test")
    example = 0

test = input()

example = 1
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This script doesn't do anything useful, so what are you actually trying to accomplish? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). For more tips, see [ask]. Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the example becomes 0, and example == 1 becomes False in the next iteration, thus exiting the loop.

Use `while True`.

Also make sure to add a sleep, else it might cause some issues.

Comment: I still want the other lines of code to be executed while the while loop checks, and obviously while True doesn't execute later code until you run break

Comment: Then you can run a separate thread of code. Chec:https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html